# Add a query result (on any computed value) to a new WIT

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am creating new WorkItemType and would like to populate parts of the WIT card in the board with computed values, examples include:

- Given a start date calculate the duration in weeks since then
- Count the number of fields that contain a valid value

I am interested in either a way to include query results in the WIT card, or how to fill a defined field with computed values.

EDIT: Running an on-prem installation of azure-dev ops and using the new process template with an inherited process

Comment: You can't really do this on a work item card, the closest you can get is adding the LinksControl to show relationships of the current item.  Check it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/define-link-controls?view=azure-devops-2019

Answer (score 0):

You may check `Query based boards` extension which allows you to visualize the result of work item queries on a board:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=realdolmen.querybasedboards

Comment: Does the Query based boards extension helps you?